# Put data in php://input from command line

Tags: php, command-line, stdin

I have a little PHP script that reads from `php://input`. With my command line I can run the script but I don't know how to "fill" the `php://input`.

I tryed using `php file.php < my_test_data` but it fills the `php://stdin` not the `php://input`

The script could be summarized in this:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('php://input'); ?>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible; `php://input` takes its data from `$_POST` request (which you won't be able to fill in the command line - unless you do real requests with something like `wget` or `curl`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`php://input` only works for scripts run from the webserver.

When CLI scripts need to access standard input, they use `php://stdin`, or the already opened stream `STDIN`:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('php://stdin'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo stream_get_contents(STDIN); ?>
```