# file_get_contents('php://input') is always empty

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to get the data of a POST request sent via cURL. I'm using `file_get_contents('php://input')` but it's always empty. What am I missing?

#### My script

```
<?php

$data_string = json_encode([ "foo" => 123 ]);


$ch = curl_init('http://httpbin.org/post');

#
# Debugging
#

# Send traffic through proxy
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');

$stderr = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $stderr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

#
# Send request
#

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
]);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "\nRESULT:\n$result";

#
# Output debugging
#

rewind($stderr);
$stderrLog = stream_get_contents($stderr);

echo "\nDEBUG:\n$stderrLog\n";

echo "\nSETTINGS:\nallow_url_fopen: ", ini_get('allow_url_fopen'), "\n";

$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "\nBODY:\n$body\n";
```

#### Script result

```
RESULT:
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"foo\":123}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "11",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  },
  "json": {
    "foo": 123
  },
  "origin": "65.199.22.138",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}

DEBUG:
*   Trying 23.21.55.239...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to httpbin.org (23.21.55.239) port 80 (#0)
> POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 11

* upload completely sent off: 11 out of 11 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: meinheld/0.6.1
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 18:08:13 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< X-Powered-By: Flask
< X-Processed-Time: 0
< Content-Length: 343
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
* Connection #0 to host httpbin.org left intact


SETTINGS:
allow_url_fopen: 1

BODY:
```

#### Additional info

- PHP version: 7.2.2
- PHP error log is receiving errors but nothing from this code
- I've verified via mitmproxy that the request is sending JSON data
- allow_url_fopen is set to true (see script)

Comment: And how are you running that script?

Comment: @PatrickQ `php ~/Projects/curl/test-posted.php` in Terminal using brewed PHP

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `php://input` is for, but this is from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) "php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body".  Since you are running this from the command line, there _is_ no request body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put data in php://input from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455941/put-data-in-php-input-from-command-line)

Comment: Oh. I was thinking it could reference the request generated by curl somehow. Is there any way for the client PHP to see the data curl is posting?

Comment: The only data that gets posted is whatever data you specify.  So in this case, just `$data_string`. You might also be interested in [curl_getinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to see some of the request details, but it's not going to give you the body (presumably because since you have to set it, you should already know what it is).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for setting me straight, Patrick Q.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents('php://input')` is what your script gets as input data **when invoked by the web server** due to a `POST` or `PUT` request received by your website.

This of course assuming the script is part of a web application.

But you run the script from the Terminal (*as I read from comments*), in this case `php://input` **is always empty**.

---

**What's happening in your script:**

You are (successfully) **sending** data (what's in `$data_string`) to `http://httpbin.org/post` with a `POST` request.

The **response** you receive back is in `$result` and from the output you posted it's some JSON encoded data.